# Ошибка в подсчете общего количества, в чем ошибка?

Tags: python, django

Необходимо подсчитать общее количество одного и того же ингредиента, но  у меня они не суммируются, а выводятся по отдельности. В чем моя ошибка?

Вот вьюха:

```
    @action(
        detail=False, methods=['get'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
    def download_shopping_cart(self, request):
        ingredients = IngredientAmount.objects.filter(
            recipe__cart__user=request.user).values(
            'ingredients__name',
            'ingredients__measurement_unit').annotate(total=Sum('amount'))

        shopping_cart = '\n'.join([
            f'{ingredient["ingredients__name"]} - {ingredient["total"]} '
            f'{ingredient["ingredients__measurement_unit"]}'
            for ingredient in ingredients
        ])
        filename = 'shopping_cart.txt'
        response = HttpResponse(shopping_cart, content_type='text/plain')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={filename}'
        return response
```

Comment: *у меня они не суммируются, а выводятся по отдельности.* Так Вы ж их не группируете - вот каждая отдельная запись и считается как группа.

Comment: спасибо за отклик, а как это можно реализовать, я еще только учусь и нашел вариант через pandas, но можно ли это сделать стандартными методами?